# OpenGL-es projection doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've tried following the lessons about drawing shapes and applying projections to them as found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/projection.html), but the projection just doesn't seem to work. As far as I know I've copy-pasted all the pieces of code in my project, here are the important code parts:

In my `Renderer` class:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

    // Draw shape
    mTriangle.draw(mMVPMatrix);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
}
```

The `draw` method of my `Triangle` class:

```
public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition"); // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle); // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer); // Prepare the triangle coordinate data

    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor"); // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0); // Set color for drawing the triangle


    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix"); // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0); // Apply the projection and view transformation

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount); // Draw the triangle

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle); // Disable vertex array
}
```

The triangle still is being stretched. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to debug in *onSurfaceChanged*? What happens in those lines? Especially:

1. - what are the passed values `width` and `height`?
   - which value does `float ratio = (float) width / height;` calculate?
   - do you see any changes to the values of *mProjMatrix* after the call `Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);`?
2. how does your `private final String fragmentShaderCode` in `class Triangle` look like? As  the order of the multiplication in the line `"  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +` is important.

Your provided code looks quiet good, difficult issue here.